# Using Python and Regex in Power Query

Tags: python, powerbi, powerquery

I have a dummy table which holds rows about postcodes and has a regex string that will identify a valid postcode.

I am trying to use python because the actual source data has a string in regex format and MS SQL doesn't support regex.

I am a newbie to Python and wanting to use Python inside power query to identify if a postode is valid for their regex string.

I have this working when Hardcoding the regex string, I am hitting an issue when trying to reference the dataset that holds the regex value.

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd
pat = r'(?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b'

dataset["New"] = dataset["Postcode"].str.replace(pat,'Inside Coverage area')
```

the above works

however, this doesnt.

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd

dataset["New"] = dataset["Postcode"].str.replace(dataset["RegexChk"],'Inside Coverage area')
```

I have dropped the variable pat but have tried with and without and it makes no difference.

This is the error I get
*TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'*

I have googled but I seem to be going in circles.

Comment: Please provide sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataset["regexChk"]` is a series not a pattern. Use the assign function to create a new column. It can iterate through the dataframe rowwise and use the data in the specified columns. Is there a regex pattern in each row of RegexChk?

Try this.

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd
dataset = (dataset
           .assign(New=dataset.apply(lambda row: row['Postcode'].replace(row["RegexChk"], 'Inside Coverage area'), 
                                     axis=1)
                   )
           )
```

Here I have added my test data

```
Postcode  ,  RegexChk
HU1       ,  (?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b
HU2       ,  (?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b
HU3       ,  (?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b
PH1       ,  (?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b
PH1       ,  (?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b
PH12      ,  (?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b
PH 1      ,  (?i:^PH)(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|14)\b
```

Comment: Yes a regex pattern is in each row  of RegexChk

made the change and still getting the 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' error

Comment: made the change getting this error now. AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Okay try this. Also it would good to have some sample data

Comment: Added test data here is latest error, thanks.   Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column New

Comment: Last time. This worked for me

Comment: Your regex also doesn't match anything

Comment: Yes that worked for me thanks, but like you say it isn't finding anything rows 4 & 5 should do. Is this because in the hardcoded version the variable has an r before the value?

Comment: [Use this to tune your regex](https://regexr.com/) In the future, please include your data in the original post, and don't modify answers. It makes it very difficult for others to read what is going on and what has been done.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted since it answers your original question